# What does the blue circle with the underlined check mark mean in GPB?

Tags: google-play-books

What does the blue circle on the right of my book list indicate in Google Play Books? You see the first book in the image below expresses this icon which described verbally is a blue circle with an underlined check mark in white font. The other books appear greyed out too, what does that indicate as well? I've also noticed other books not greyed out that do not have the blue circle.

[image: screen shot of Google play books library view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkmark in the blue circle means that this book has been downloaded to your device (if you'll notice, it's the same icon as the download notification in the top left).

The books without the checkmark are ones that you have purchased (or uploaded) and are available for download. The reason that they're currently grayed out is that you're not currently online, so you can't access those books until you get an internet connection.